# Fair quiz without registration, is it possible in webapp?

Tags: unique, vote

I'm going to make simple quiz form on site.

Are there ways to make it fair, that nobody vote up multiple times.

There are some ways to identify uniqueness of vote with their lacks:

- ***Cookies*** - the simplest and easy to eliminate
- ***IP*** - not stable,because of DHCP and local networks
- **Captcha** or **mail registration** - not user friendly and complicate the process.

What is your experience for fair and user-friendly quiz?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're worried about cookies being too easy to eliminate/game, you can use **[evercookie](http://blog.depthsecurity.com/2010/09/super-persistent-cookies-evercookie.html)**. It's a JavaScript API that's billed as ""virtually irrevocable persistent cookies".

Comment: may these cookie affect on SEO and Firewall or antivirus.I mean,that looks like these cookies are hidden behind other file types. May it be suspicious for client's antivirus?

Comment: They are cookies. They can't affect firewall. Not sure if some malware checker would dislike them. No idea about SEO.